# ActiveJob deliver_later not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have the following method:

```
UserMailer.comment_alert(@comment, user, type).deliver_later
```

Which oddly shows up with the param `deliver_now` in the rails log:

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 5bdf9ed1-53d5-42aa-acb2-7ce54ab284e1) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "comment_alert", "deliver_now", gid://xxx/Comment/153, gid://xxx/User/26, "Comment"
```

The job never processes, and I see nothing in the Sidekiq log. There is also no mail delivered, ever. I tried restarting sidekiq, rails, and redis, and even clearing the redis db. Interestingly changing to `.deliver_now` works, but this doesn't seem to touch sidekiq or create an `Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob`

In my application.rb:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I am using **rails 4.2.6** with **activejob 4.2.6**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mailers are queued in the queue mailers. Remember to start sidekiq processing that queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

Or add `config/sidekiq.yml` with the following content

```
  :verbose: true
  :concurrency: 25
  :queues:
    - [mailers, 7]
    - [default, 5]
```

And run `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

Comment: Thank you for solving that for me.

Comment: This **-q default -q mailers** is help for me at 2017. Sidekiq 5.0.5, Rails 5.1.4. Thank you!

Comment: Kenny thank you! Awesome answer, got this out of the plate after several days of frustration. Who knew you have to ask for your new car to come with wheels...

Comment: If you put the config at `config/sidekiq.yml` you should not need to pass it to `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: This worked on the branch, but now that it's merged to the development branch, it suddenly stopped working.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score -3):

If you are working with sidekiq don't use deliver later because the job never performs, instead use perform_in(<>) and call a worker with deliver_now inside