# deliver_later with ActionMailer not sending mail in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

deliver_later with ActionMailer not sending mail in production.

I am using

> rails 5.2.0 and
>   delayed_job_active_record 4.1.3

I have tried `deliver` and `deliver_now` in production and the email is getting sent successfully. As soon as I change to `deliver_later`, the job gets queued but it's never executed.

```
if user.notify_new_event?
   EventMailer.notify_created(user.id, id).deliver_later
end
```

`deliver_later` with `ActionMailer` should behave like `deliver_later` with `ActiveJob`. But some how the `deliver_later` with `ActionMailer` is not working.

Comment: Not a whole lot of detail, but possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871943/activejob-deliver-later-not-sending)... ?  Let us know.

Comment: Not exactly. I have started the delayed job server in the production using
`RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start`

Comment: My question is basically on `gem delayed_job_active_record`. Please checkout this documentation https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: OK, are jobs showing up in the database?  What's in your `.log` file?  As my first comment mentioned, we don't have a lot of detail to help you without knowing what you've validated first.

Comment: Jobs are correctly getting inserted in the database. But the job execution never starts even if the job server is up.

This is my delayed job log.
`I, [2019-01-02T13:26:20.532345 #17000]  INFO -- : 2019-01-02T13:26:20+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:clapp pid:17000)] Starting job worker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the problem with `ActionMailer` with `DelayedJob`. Rather the problem was with multi-tenant application. By default `delayed_job` was trying to execute job from the default tenant.